# How can I authenticate with a keyfile when using ssh-copy-id?

Tags: ssh

Is this possible? If so how?

The server that I want to copy a ssh key to, only allows authentication with a keyfile rather than username and password.

I am able to login to the server with `ssh -i ...`

Answer (score 0):

I just checked and ssh-copy-id supports the -i [identity_file] option just like you would use it for ssh.

If that doesn't work for you, you can see if your version can do this option:

```
-o ssh -o IdentityFile ~/backups/.ssh/id_dsa
```

Next you could try updating your version of ssh-copy-id. 
Lastly, you can simply copy/paste the public key after you ssh in.

Comment: How does this `-o` option work exactly?

Answer (score 0):

If you have your ssh-agent running and the old key with which you can already log in is loaded it should work like this:

```
ssh-copy-id -i new-key user@host
```

or

```
ssh-copy-id -i new-key host-alias-from-config
```

I had to add `-f` but I am not sure if that was an error on my part.